How many balls in your friend’s urn (before you take any out)?
Your friend tells you: This is a remarkable urn. It contains only red and black balls. If you reach in and take one ball at random, there’s an equal chance of drawing red or black. So you might think that if you instead take two at random, it’s 50/50 that your balls will match. Well, you’d be wrong — but if they do match, and then you reach your other hand in and take two more, the chances your second pair match each other are 50/50!
How many balls in your friend’s urn (before you take any out)?
Clarification:  Balls match if they are the same color.

Attribution:  momath.org

Simply by telling a story about a friend having a remarkable urn, this non research 'math problem' IMO is turned into a recreational 'math puzzle' which can be presented to any interested audience. I hope there remains some room for such questions here.


 $\boxed {6}$  Just algebra.  Say $N$ is the common number of red and black, at the start.  Then, after the first pair is removed, there are $N$ of one and $N-2$ of the other, so the probability of a pair is now $$\frac {N(N-1)+(N-2)(N-3)}{(2N-2)(2N-3)}$$  Setting that to $\frac 12$ and solving yields $N=3$.


+1 This is exactly how I solved this puzzle.

@Will.Octagon.Gibson  Funny side note:  I passed the equation to Wolfram Alpha just to check the arithmetic and it found a different result (an obviously incorrect one).  Took me a while to sort out that it interpreted my variable name as a function, at least in one term.   Not the first time that using a computer as a sanity check has massively confused a simple issue.


 Two balls - one red and one black. By the principle of explosion, if you reach in and take out two of the same colour, everything is true.


No logical shenanigans are required - you're just as likely to draw a pair followed by another pair as you are to draw a pair followed by no pair.
